# Trying to save original name of uploaded pdf on my sql table

Tags: php, sql, pdf, file-upload

Im uploading pdfs with this code below:

```
$folder = '../uploads/pdfs';
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');
$pdf = $_FILES['pdf'];
$ext = substr($pdf['name'],-3);
$pdf_name = $pdf['name'].'-FROM-'.$date_begin.'-TO-'.$date_end.'';
$f['pdf'] = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$pdf_name.'.'.$ext;
move_uploaded_file($pdf['tmp_name'], $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$pdf["name"]);
```

Im my sql table when I do the insert, **Im getting this in my *pdf_name* field**:

*2014/05/F:\Xampp\tmp\phpE92C.tmp*

And I want to save my pdf in sql **like this**:

*2014/05/nameofpdf.pdf*

Do you see what Im doing wrong here?

My insert sql statment:

```
$inseretInPdf = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pdfs (pdf_name, date_begin, date_end) VALUES (:pdf_name, :date_begin, :date_end)");  
$inseretInPdf->bindValue(':pdf_name', $f['pdf']);
$inseretInPdf->bindValue(':date_begin', $f['date_begin']);
$inseretInPdf->bindValue(':date_end', $f['date_end']);
$inseretInPdf->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passing the full path with `$inseretInPdf->bindValue(':pdf_name', $f['pdf']);`

which is:

`$f['pdf'] = $year .'/'.$month .'/'.$f['url'].'.'.$ext;
              2014  /    05     /  F:\Xampp\tmp\phpE92C  .  tmp`

So change `$f['pdf']` to what you want it to display when it's added to the database.

**EDIT:** I updated the answer to visually show you what `$f` was passing. (:

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my $f['pdf'] = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$pdf_name.'.'.$ext; its what I want to save in my sql table that is 2014/05/pdfname.pdf! But I dont understand why is saving like temporary file: 2014/05/F:\Xampp\tmp\phpE92C.tmp

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($pdf['tmp_name'], $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$pdf["name"]);` change the `$pdf['tmp_name']` to `$pdf['name']`

Comment: That way, the pdf is not uploading!

Comment: Ok I must be out of it and not sure why I even recommended that, `$f['pdf'] = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$pdf['name'].'.'.$ext;` this should do the trick.

Comment: You deserve it Skewled!! x) By the way do you know if it is possbile give a default name for pdfs that are uploading? Because I want all the pdfs that are uploading with same first name! Something like $pdf['tmp_name'] = "TestName";
      move_uploaded_file($pdf['tmp_name'], $folder.'-'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$pdf['name']); (but its not working like this(

Comment: I was just getting back on the pc ha nice one (: